# JavaScript window.open() does not work when called from inside Ajax TabContainer

Tags: javascript, ajaxcontroltoolkit

This is a block of code that used to work when the page was devoid of any Ajax

```
if (sStat > "") {
    str2 = "Dist.aspx?statProducer="; str2 += document.all.txtHiddenStat.value;
    var distWindow;
    if (document.all.ddlWindows.value == "new") {
       distWindow = window.open(str2);
    }
    else {
        distWindow = window.open(str2, "PeriscopeView");
        distWindow.focus();
    }
    return false;
```

The input is gathered inside this Ajax TabContainer in a text box inside the "advSearch" TabPanel. A search button, when clicked, calls the doValidate() JavaScript method. The code above exists inside that method.

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="_toolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

<form id = "frmSearch" onsubmit="return(doValidate());" method="post" runat="server">
<asp:TabContainer ID="AdvOrBasicSearch" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0">
<div id="tabs_header">
    <span id="tab1" class="ajax_tab_active">
    <asp:TabPanel ID="basicSearch" runat="server" HeaderText="Basic Search">.../asp:TabPanel>                

    </span>
    <span id="tab2" class="ajax_tab_active">
    <asp:TabPanel ID="advSearch" runat="server" HeaderText="Advanced Search">...</asp:TabPanel>
    </span>
</div>
</asp:TabContainer>
</form>
```

Now that the Ajax TabContainers are being used on the page, the second window will open, however it just hangs/time's out.

EDIT

Thought I'd add to this post as I've been stepping through the code to try and find out what's wrong. After that block of JavaScript executes Visual Studio will, after the "return false" line of code, navigate to a page with the following header:

```
// Name:        MicrosoftAjax.debug.js
// Assembly:    AjaxControlToolkit
// Version:     4.1.60623.0
// FileVersion: 4.1.60623
// (c) 2010 CodePlex Foundation
```

This is where the program hangs. I am about 5 minutes into stepping through the code being executed on this page, and it appears as almost every single one of the 7000+ lines of code are going to be called. Is there a way to make the TabContainer skip whatever it is doing here?

Comment: document.all is IE5 code. DO NOT USE IT.

Comment: This is something I've been updating so thanks for that catch. The same problem still exists, however.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. I missed the document.all.txtHiddenStat.value, and after altering this line too it seems to run *a little* bit faster. The secondary page/window will still open now however it still takes a very long time.